# ring theory and ideals of them

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ and $J$ be two ideals of it. We know that $I+J$ is a subset of $R$ and moreover, $I+J$ is an ideal of $R$.
**Question:** When $I+J$ can be $R$?

Comment: When $1\in I+J$?

Comment: Read about co-prime ideals. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Coprime_Ideals

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown this will depend on if $1 \in R$ is assumed as part of definition of the ring.